# RegEx for matching specific chars

Tags: arrays, regex

Separating question text from question options. How do I get this?

*I tried it but it doesn't work very well:*

```
 /(\d+)\.\s*([A-Z].*?)\s+([A-Z]\..*?)\s*[A-Z]|$)/s
```

**Plaint Text:**

> 12. Whatti..

**Goal:**

> What  rer?
>
> A. Porce idge
>
> B) Pl ge
>
> C; Cla attachments
>
> D: Removable partial laminar denture for the upper jaw
>
> E: Swa part
>
> 13. A 7- parotitis (mumps)

This is a question text. The options in the question text are specified as (A, B, C, D, E..). I'm trying to differentiate these question options.

Comment: Can you give use a couple of examples of the data you are working with?

Comment: It's still unclear. You need to give us some _proper_ examples. What result are you expecting? We can't help if we don't know what result you're looking for. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @J.Doe3 I didn't downvote but you still need to provide examples of input and expected output.

Comment: @jeff I've updated the question. Hopefully this time with understandable content

Comment: Where does the text come from and why are the list points inconsistent like that? Seems like this should be fixed on when the text is created instead, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we only wish to detect three listed chars, we would be starting with a simple expression such as:

```
(\.|\(|\))
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/iUKI6d/1)

For the desired goal, our expression would become a bit more complicated, we could start with a expression such as:

```
([A-Z]\.|[A-Z]\)|[A-Z]:|[A-Z];|[0-9]+\.)
```

and we would be adding to it, as new cases might come up using alternation.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/e3RqpY/1)

#### Test

```
$re = '/([A-Z]\.|[A-Z]\)|[A-Z]:|[A-Z];|[0-9]+\.)/m';
$str = 'What denture construction would be optimal for this patient, considering his occupation as a lecturer? A.Porcelain-fused-to-metal dental bridge B)Plastic dental bridge C;Clasp-retained (bugel) removable partial denture with attachments D:Removable partial laminar denture for the upper jaw E.Swaged-soldered metal dental bridge with faceted intermediate part 13. A 7-year-old boy is diagnosed with epi- demic parotitis (mumps).';
$subst = '\\n Option: $1 ';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: The regex isn't complete for the OP's text though. It's still not matching `C;` and `D:`. Here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/mrvQh

Comment: No wonder, the input is really bad! Using regular expressions for matching irregular data isn't an easy task :-p

Comment: Applaudable answer, thank you @Emma - Is it possible to print styles with `foreach`? I'm giving you an example. `foreach ($options as $option) { echo "Option: " . $option . "<br>"; } ` like this, possible ?

Comment: Again **thank you** in advance for your help @Emma I'm waiting for you to update impatiently :))

Comment: Sorry I've realized now :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but this will do:

```
$text = "What denture construction would be optimal for this patient, considering his occupation as a lecturer? A.Porcelain-fused-to-metal dental bridge B)Plastic dental bridge C;Clasp-retained (bugel) removable partial denture with attachments D:Removable partial laminar denture for the upper jaw E.Swaged-soldered metal dental bridge with faceted intermediate part 13. A 7-year-old boy is diagnosed with epi- demic parotitis (mumps).";

$symbol = ":";
//Put whatever symbol you wish to use to create a more uniform output

$replacement = preg_replace("/((?:[A-Z]{1}|[0-9]{2}))((?:\\.|\\)|;|:))([ A-Z]{1})/", "\r\n$1{$symbol} $3", $text);

echo $replacement;
```

This will output:

```
What denture construction would be optimal for this patient, considering his occupation as a lecturer? 
A: Porcelain-fused-to-metal dental bridge 
B: Plastic dental bridge 
C: Clasp-retained (bugel) removable partial denture with attachments 
D: Removable partial laminar denture for the upper jaw 
E: Swaged-soldered metal dental bridge with faceted intermediate part 
13:  A 7-year-old boy is diagnosed with epi- demic parotitis (mumps).
```

Caveat, there is a very real chance of false positives, because the regex is pretty flexible.

You're probably better off cleaning the input. If I were to guess, I would have guessed that your input is a PDF copy/paste job. See if you can import more formatting from the source.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/h4OA9

Comment: If you're copying from PDF, make sure you copy the formatting also. You can do that by copying into PHP or Notepad++. That should save the line breaks, which will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "styles with `foreach`".